# Obtener numeros impares de una fila de una matriz y colocar el porcentaje de cada fila en un arreglo

Tags: java

Tengo un problema y es que cuando lo sumo me imprime demasiadas lineas

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class unm4sk
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int array []=new int [5];
    int SFil;
    //TABLA CON DATOS YA INDICADOS EN EL EXAMEN
    int tabla[][] = {
                        { 95, 45, 37, 70, 85 },
                        { -4, 10, 92, 49, 48 },
                        { 2, 30, 51, 100, -9 }
                     };

    for(int i = 0; i<tabla.length; i++)
    {
     for(int j = 0; j<tabla[i].length; j++)
      {
        if (tabla[i][j]%2!=0)
        {
          for (int k=0;k<3 ;k++ )
          {
            SFil=0;
            for (int p=0;p<5 ;p++ )
            {
              SFil=SFil+tabla[i][j];
              System.out.print("\nLa suma de la fila "+k+1+" es: "+SFil);
            }
            System.out.println();
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tal como está ahora mismo, por cada elemento estás haciendo 15 prints ( 3 del indice k y por cada uno 5 del índice p). Entiendo que ese print deberías hacerlo donde tienes el println para hacer lo que tú quieres. Por otra parte no acabo de entender para qué tienes ese índice k si la fila te la indica el índice i. Yo creo que ese bucle de K sobra. Intenta mejorar la redacción de la pregunta porque es bastante escueta y confusa

Comment: Ya intente de todo llevo horas buscando como hacerle pero me revuelvo cada vez mas solo quiero que una tabla ya llenada pueda sacarle sus porcentajes y ponerlos en un arreglo.

Comment: es decir, ¿quieres saber cuál es el porcentaje de impares en cada fila?

Comment: de cada fila sacar el porcentaje de solo impares y pasarlos a un arreglo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según lo comentado en la pregunta, creo que lo que quieres es lo siguiente:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class unm4sk
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    int array []=new int[3];
    int SFil;
    //TABLA CON DATOS YA INDICADOS EN EL EXAMEN
    int tabla[][] = {
                        { 95, 45, 37, 70, 85 },
                        { -4, 10, 92, 49, 48 },
                        { 2, 30, 51, 100, -9 }
                     };
    //Recorro las filas
    for(int i = 0; i<tabla.length; i++)
    {
        //Inicializo el contador a 0
        SFil=0;
        //Recorro los elemntos de la fila i
        for(int j = 0; j<tabla[i].length; j++)
        {   
            //Compruebo si el elemento es impar, y en caso de serlo incremento el contador
            if (tabla[i][j]%2!=0)
            {
                SFil++; 
            }
        }
        //Caculo el porcentaje y lo guardo en la posición del array correspondiente a la fila i
        array[i]=(100*SFil)/tabla[i].length;
        System.out.println("\nLa fila "+i+" tiene "+SFil+" números impares ("+array[i]+"%)");
    }
  }
}
```

Recorro cada fila (índice i) y cuento cuantos elementos impares hay (cada elemento se recorre con el índice j e incremento variable "SFil" si el elemento es impar).
Al final del conteo por cada fila, calculo el porcentaje y lo guardo en la posición correspondiente a la fila en la variable "array" (array[i]) y lo muestro por consola.

Comment: Oye muchas gracias!!! <3 no sabes de la que me acabas de salvar y bueno creo que tendré que batallar mas te lo agradezco muchísimo hoy tengo un examen y estoy estudiando todo lo que pueda venir....Te lo agradezco mucho.

Comment: Acabo de añadir comentarios al código para que quede más claro

Comment: No se como agradecertelo encerio, estoy en deuda con usted.